# Null customer_address_id on sales_flat_order_address table

Tags: orders, sales-order, customer-address

Does somebody know why field **customer_address_id** is null on **sales_flat_order_address** table? As regards to order for customer who has an address.

In class: **Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address** I found this:

protected function _beforeSave()

```
{
    parent::_beforeSave();

    if (!$this->getParentId() && $this->getOrder()) {
        $this->setParentId($this->getOrder()->getId());
    }

    // Init customer address id if customer address is assigned
    if ($this->getCustomerAddress()) {
        $this->setCustomerAddressId($this->getCustomerAddress()->getId());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `customer_address_id` is a reference to the `customer_address` table.
When placing an order as guest you have to fill in the address manually.
When you do that there is no customer address object to reference in the checkout so `customer_address_id` is null.
This also happens when you checkout as a customer, but fill in a new address and you DO NOT choose to save the address in your address book.

The field has a value only when you checkout as a logged in customer and select one of the addresses in your address book, or you add a new address and choose to save it in your address book.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. Cause of problem was a custom modification of opc.